# Wine desktop clipping to fit the screen - how do I turn it off?

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I have a Windows program I run in Wine, requiring a desktop slightly taller then the vertical workspace of my netbook's screen. When I create the desktop, Wine clips it to fit the screen.

I have to set it top all, grab it, move it up, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> to resize it.

Is there a way to stop it from clipping in the first place? Running without a desktop still clips it but then I can't resize or move it.

Comment: If the desktop is partially moved off screen before the program re-sizes it; then Clipping does not occur.  And then it can be grabbed and moved where it is needed.  Of course this only saves resizing, both top all and grab/move still need to be done.  So it is replacing a resizing with a quick grab and move.  Only slightly better.